# How to refer to dynamically created variables

Tags: ruby, variables, arguments, instance-variables

My script creates some variables like this:

```
instance_variable_set "@_#{pos}", dir
```

where `pos` is an integer. This gives me some instance variables `@_1`, `@_2`, `@_3`, etc. My script receives an argument (a number) from the command line, and that number needs to refer to an instance variable created like this:

```
puts $path.gsub(@_(pos), "")
```

For example, if `ARGV[0]` is `1`, then I need to use var `@_1` in a command like `gsub` like this:

```
puts $path.gsub(@_1, "")
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `instance_variable_get` function: [rubydoc](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-instance_variable_get)

Comment: thankyou, i've solved like you said:   puts $path.gsub((instance_variable_get "@_#{ARGV[1]}"), "")